# Filter change log to a particular folder and sub-folders

Tags: git

I'm mostly talking about GUIs here, such as [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/), but I'll be grateful for any answer, even command line.

When studying git history, it is easy to filter *log* to only show commits, that include files that have a specified file system ancestor - I do not have problems with this part.

When examining a particular commit itself, however I cannot find and easy way to filter out anything that does not have a given file system ancestor. In small commits (as they should be) this is not a problem, but when a commit has dozens of files (it sucks but it happens) it's very hard to find the changes I'm interested in.

What are UI features (in your favourite UI git client) or correct command line git usage, to show diffs only for the files that have a given file system ancestor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to show diffs only for the files that have a given file system ancestor...

I hope i understand you correctly and correct me if i am wrong.

Are you looking for this:

```
git log --follow -- <path>
```

it will display the history of a given file and will output all the commits in which the file was modified.

Comment: Thank you for this. So this part I've figured out as I explain in the first part of my question. It's the other part that is giving me troubles. I added clarification in the question, that I do not have problem with this part.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean here: `When examining a particular commit itself, however I cannot find and easy way to filter out anything that does not have a given file system ancestor.`

Comment: A commit can contain dozens of files. Only some of them are located in a particular folder or its sub-folders (recursively). I'm only interested in seeing diffs from these when looking at a particular commit. How can I make sure that other files diffs (that are outside of the given folder) are not displayed. Thank you for taking time to understand my question and asking for a clarification

Comment: In this case you can extract them out to  new branch and this branch will only contains those files.

Comment: `git subtree split -P <name-of-folder> -b <name-of-new-branch>`

Comment: So I need a new branch just to examine history? That's... tough.

Comment: you can follow file with the --follow or extract the full folder with the subtree since you want only part of each commit

Comment: Okay, +1, thank you for helping me out. TFS UI (when you are not using GIt) groups up all the diffs in a commit in a tree-like UI and it is very easy to see the group of files you need in a commit together. Unfortunately it does not quite work for Git. I was hoping for something along these lines.

Comment: I'm actually going to accept that, because I found out that the git command line filters diffs by default. `git log -p <folder>` does exactly what I want. I fell quite silly, thank you for bearing with me.